# Mysql select query summimg two columns and getting first values from two other columns

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to sum two columns and get first entered values for two other column.

example table

```
trans,invoice,email,amount,ticket,date
111,inv-111,pp@gmail.com,15.00,3,"2014-09-13 15:20:12"
125,inv-125,ab@gmail.com,10.00,2,"2014-09-13 15:15:40"
132,inv-132,ab@gmail.com,10.00,2,"2014-09-13 15:17:19"
145,inv-145,ab@gmail.com,5.00,1,"2014-09-13 15:17:52"
199,inv-199,pp@gmail.com,5.00,1,"2014-09-13 15:18:18"
```

This is what I get with:

select sum(amount) as amount, sum(ticket) as ticket, trans, invoice, email, min(date) from trans group by email;

```
amount,ticket,trans,invoice,email,min(date)
25.00,5,125,inv-125,ab@gmail.com,"2014-09-13 15:15:40"
20.00,4,111,inv-111,pp@gmail.com,"2014-09-13 15:18:18"
```

desired result: I would like the invoice and trans column to be from the first date.

```
amount,ticket,trans,invoice,email,min(date)
25.00,5,125,inv-125,ab@gmail.com,"2014-09-13 15:15:40"
20.00,4,199,inv-199,pp@gmail.com,"2014-09-13 15:18:18"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select sum(amount) as amount, sum(ticket) as ticket,
       substring_index(group_concat(trans order by date asc), ',', 1) as trans,
       substring_index(group_concat(invoice order by date asc), ',', 1) as invoice,
       email,
       min(date)
from trans
group by email;
```

Note that this puts the values into a long string. This usually works in practice, but there is a default length on the intermediate string of around 1000 characters.  Also, this resulting data type is a string rather than a number, which might affect the `trans` column.  The output looks the same, but the underlying data type is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do what you are doing on a pre-sorted data. Use subquery to pre-sort by date so it picks up the minimum.

```
SELECT sum( n.amount ) AS amount, sum( n.ticket ) AS ticket, n.trans, n.invoice, n.email, min( n.date ) 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM test
ORDER BY date
) AS n
GROUP BY email
```

output:

```
amount  ticket  trans  invoice  email  min(n.date)  
25 5 125 inv-125 ab@gmail.com 2014-09-13 15:15:40 
20 4 199 inv-199 pp@gmail.com 2014-09-13 15:18:18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by using a self join

```
select 
t1.amount,
t1.ticket,
t.email,
t.trans,
t.invoice,
t.date
from test t
join (
     select min(date) date,
      email,
      sum(amount) as amount, 
      sum(ticket) as ticket
      from test 
      group by email
     ) t1
on(t.email = t1.email and t.date = t1.date)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9442eb/2)</kbd>

Comment: @user4040054 care to accept the answer which best suits you and if all are works fine then accept the answer which is posted first see [*How does accepting an answer work*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)